# Convert Excel formula to Power BI

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi

Im a new user in Power BI and im having a lot of trouble trying to convert my formulas in excel to work in Power BI.

My main issue is figuring out how to convert **IF(AND(OR** and **several IF's**. I have several formulas similar to this one so with the help of converting this one I could most likely do the rest based off this one.

**Parameters** would be a table in power bi.

**E2, Q2, $B$2, etc**. would be columns/fields in different tables in power bi.

```
=IF(E2="";"";IF(AND(OR(E2="Critical";E2="Maximum";E2="Urgent");Q2*24>Parameters!$B$2);"NO";
                                IF(AND(OR(E2="Alta";E2="High");Q2*24>Parameters!$B$3);"NO";
                                  IF(AND(OR(E2="Media";E2="Medium");Q2*24>Parameters!$B$4);"NO";
                                    IF(AND(OR(E2="Baja";E2="Low");Q2*24>Parameters!$B$5);"NO";
                               "YES")))))
```

This formula would be in a new column inside one of the tables.

Comment: That's a really poor spec - "columns in other tables"... Will be much easier to offer advice with a clearer picture of your data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already did the work, it's very very similar, I've just added a new column and modify your formula like this:

```
Column = IF(Table1[E2]="","",
            IF(AND(OR(Table1[E2]="Critical",OR(Table1[E2]="Maximum",Table1[E2]="Urgent")),Table1[Q2]*24>Table1[B2]),"No",
                IF(AND(OR(Table1[E2]="Alta",Table1[E2]="High"),Table1[Q2]*24>Table1[B2]),"No",
                    IF(AND(OR(Table1[E2]="Media",Table1[E2]="Medium"),Table1[Q2]*24>Table1[B2]),"No",
                        IF(AND(OR(Table1[E2]="Baja",Table1[E2]="Low"),Table1[Q2]*24>Table1[B2]),"No","YES"
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
```

Where Table1 is my table, E2,Q2 and B2 are my columns name. About the "Q2*24", because you look like to use always Q2 and not Q2,Q3,Q4,... you can use one VAR instead of a full column with always the same value, like this:

```
Column = 
VAR ReplaceQ2 = 10
RETURN 
IF(Table1[E2]="","",
            IF(AND(OR(Table1[E2]="Critical",OR(Table1[E2]="Maximum",Table1[E2]="Urgent")),ReplaceQ2*24>Table1[B2]),"No",
                IF(AND(OR(Table1[E2]="Alta",Table1[E2]="High"),ReplaceQ2*24>Table1[B2]),"No",
                    IF(AND(OR(Table1[E2]="Media",Table1[E2]="Medium"),ReplaceQ2*24>Table1[B2]),"No",
                        IF(AND(OR(Table1[E2]="Baja",Table1[E2]="Low"),ReplaceQ2*24>Table1[B2]),"No","YES"
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
```

Hope this help

Comment: im getting the following error: The operations of comparison DAX doesnt allow values of comparison of type integer with values of type Text. Consider the posibility of using the function VALUE or FORMAT to convert one of the values.

Comment: I think the problem come from theses lines: --- Table1[Q2]*24>Table1[B2] ---. The Table1 is a value because it's a multiplication but I think your B2 Column are stored as Text, you can modify the type without DAX, just change the column type.

Answer (score 0):

=IF(AND(LEFT(L6,3)="CGK",LEFT(M6,3)="CGK"),"Intracity",IF(AND(LEFT(N6,3)="CTC",LEFT(L6,3)=LEFT(M6,3)),"Intracity",IF(AND(LEFT(L6,3)=LEFT(M6,3),LEFT(N6,3)<>"CTC"),"Intercity","Domestik")))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).